# Phoenix connection from NIFI on a kerberos cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi, apache-phoenix

I am trying to connect Phoenix on kerberos cluster from NiFi's DBCP Connection Pool.
But failed in creating JDBC driver.[image]

DataBase connection URL: jdbc:phoenix:namenode1.KTCPS08232017.ONMICROSOFT.COM:8765:nn_AzureClu/namenode@KTCPS08232017.ONMICROSOFT.COM:C:\Hadoop_Conf\nn_AzureClu.keytab

Comment: my general experience is you do not want to connection pool with Phoenix.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this HCC post](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/139693/connecting-to-phoenix-on-kerberized-cluster-from-n.html), there is a workaround:

use the Phoenix Query Server and JDBC Thin Client instead. It doesn't require any of the hadoop resources. However there does appear to be a performance penalty for large numbers of inserts.